# How to install Luxrender?

Tags: add-on, installation, luxrender-render-engine

I need a manual download link for the Blender addon so that I can copy this .py to the add on folder and then I hope I can switch to the Luxrender option in Blender 2.75.

After following the normal installation process there is no addon installed. I am using Windows 7 64-bit operating system.

Any idea what's wrong?

The installation process by Inseln looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to follow the installation instruction [here](http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxBlend_2.5_installation_instructions)?

Below the main instructions there is a link to a [development builds repository](https://bitbucket.org/luxrender/luxblend25/downloads) where you can get a .zip file which also contains Python files. But you have to follow instructions for that package, too.

Answer (score 1):

**Luxblend** Add-on is required to connect both applications.

---

For **windows** make sure you've enabled *Exporters* during the installation process, then you'll find a zip folder called **LuxBlend.zip** in your luxrender installation directory.

[image]

For **Linux** download the archive and extract it. The extracted archive contains a Luxblend folder which contains the **LuxBlend.zip**.

---

In Blender open up the **User Preferences** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>), select the *Add-ons* tab, click *Install from File* and navigate to the installation directory in order to install the Add-on:

[image]